# Comparar fechas DateTime entity Framewok

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, datetime

Hago una consulta para obtener registros con un dia y hora específico pero filtra solo por dia, no por hora.

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Notificacion(DateTime fecha)
    {
        ViewBag.Notificacion = db.tb_notificacion.Include("tb_cliente").Where(a => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(a.fecha) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(fecha)).ToList();
        return View();
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el parametro de envia correctamente, tambien llega correctamente, pero falla al filtrar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola puedes separar la parte de fecha y la hora y hacer comparacion individualmente? mira que sale un + en el resultado

Comment: porque no quitas el DbFunctions.TruncateTime() ? eso esta eliminando la hora del filtro

Comment: `DbFunctions` sin esto no encuentra nada, me devuelve vacio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al igual que los valores DateTime en .NET, los campos en la base de datos (sean de tipo datetime, datetime2, etc...) tienen una precisión fraccionaria. Para poder filtrar por la hora, debe ser la misma incluyendo esa precisión.

No es lo mismo 28/11/2019+04:56:00 que 28/11/2019+04:56:00.035.

Puedes eliminar esa precisión en la BD si no te interesa o (más complicado) quitarla al momento de filtrar, por ejemplo:

```
foos.SingleOrDefault(f => f.EntryDate.Year == bar.EntryDate.Year &&
                          f.EntryDate.Month == bar.EntryDate.Month &&
                          f.EntryDate.Day == bar.EntryDate.Day &&
                          f.EntryDate.Hour == bar.EntryDate.Hour &&
                          f.EntryDate.Minute == bar.EntryDate.Minute &&
                          f.EntryDate.Second == bar.EntryDate.Second);
```